# How to set Text in C# code?

Tags: c#, unity, text

I'm trying to make a series of text appear programmatically. It's not quite showing up, and I'm struggling to understand exactly why. Any ideas?

```
GameObject row = new GameObject("Row");
row.transform.parent = panel.transform;
HorizontalLayoutGroup rowLayoutGroup = row.AddComponent<HorizontalLayoutGroup>();
rowLayoutGroup.childForceExpandHeight = false;

GameObject name = new GameObject("Name");
name.transform.parent = row.transform;
GameObject value = new GameObject("Value");
value.transform.parent = row.transform;

Text nameText = name.AddComponent<Text>();
nameText.text = tup.First;
nameText.alignment = TextAnchor.MiddleRight;
```

Note that this script is run from a Panel, contained within a Canvas.

Comment: We'll need to know more about how the GameObject called "name" is set up in your scene hierarchy. Right now it could be just about anything - maybe it's out of the camera frame, or sized too small to contain the text you're giving it, or culled by a mask, layer, active, or enabled setting somewhere in the chain...

Comment: @DmGregory I've added more information, however, I figured out the real problem, and that was that the font wasn't included. Sigh. Well, I have it now, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It seems the problem is that I don't have a font specified, as determined by playing with the inspector text that came out. To do that, I simply needed to add the following text to my listed code.

```
nameText.font= Resources.GetBuiltinResource(typeof(Font), "Arial.ttf") as Font;
```